# SQL Server function invocation syntax question

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

The following excerpt is extract from [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176050.aspx).

> CURRENT_USER (Transact-SQL)
>
> Returns the name of the current user. This function is equivalent to
>   USER_NAME().

When I execute the two function with the following TSQL scripts (the questionable ones were commented), I'm confused about the invocation syntax. I want to know when to use the parenthesis and when not. Thanks!

```
SELECT CURRENT_USER
-- SELECT CURRENT_USER() -- Error!
SELECT USER_NAME()
-- SELECT USER_NAME -- Error!
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ones without parentheses such as `CURRENT_USER` and `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` are there for `ANSI 92` compliance. There are only five such [Niladic Functions](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/nullary) and the list hasn't changed since SQL Server 6.0.

1. [CURRENT_USER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176050.aspx)
2. [CURRENT_TIMESTAMP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188751.aspx)
3. [SESSION_USER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177587.aspx)
4. [SYSTEM_USER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179930.aspx)
5. [USER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186738.aspx)

Most other SQL Server system functions require parentheses.

The exception to this are those functions that [used to be known as global variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187953.aspx) that are prefixed with `@@` such as `@@SPID`.

This last group of functions can be passed directly in a parameter list to a stored procedure. Neither of the other two variants can.